# php chmod parent directory influence

Tags: php, chmod

Question: If a parent folder has lower than 777 permissions for everyone (755, 753 etc.), will that have any influence on a deeper placed folders?

Example:

I have three folders (one in another), let's say: "f1/f2/f3"
In folder "f2" I have "script.php" file, which tries to set "f3" folder from 755 to 777 permission rights:

```
<?
chmod("/f3",0777);
?>
```

"f1" an "f3" are 755, "f2" and "script.php" are 777.

I run script.php from a browser, but it doesn't work.

Comment: This would be a good link for you to read to better your understanding of directory permissions: http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/22/linux-permissions-demystified/